# Azure functions using Java - How to created @BlobTrigger

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

i need to created Azure function BlobTrigger using Java to monitor my storage container for new and updated blobs.

tried with below code

```
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;

@FunctionName("testblobtrigger")
 public String testblobtrigger(@BlobTrigger(name = "test", path = "testcontainer/{name}") String content) {
     try {
         return String.format("Blob content : %s!", content);

     } catch (Exception e) {
         // Output the stack trace.
         e.printStackTrace();
         return "Access Error!";
     }
 }
```

when executed it is showing error

> Storage binding (blob/queue/table) must have non-empty connection. Invalid storage binding found on method:

it is working when added connection string

```
public String kafkablobtrigger(@BlobTrigger(name = "test", path = "testjavablobstorage/{name}",connection=storageConnectionString) String content) {
```

why i need to add connection string when using blobtrigger?

in C# it is working without connection string:

```
public static void ProcessBlobContainer1([BlobTrigger("container1/{blobName}")] CloudBlockBlob blob, string blobName)
{
    ProcessBlob("container1", blobName, blob);
}
```

i didn't see any Java sample for Azure functions for @BlobTrigger.

Comment: C# falls back to default configuration name. Maybe java doesn't? What's the problem with adding connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, `connection` is necessary for the trigger to identify where the container locates.

After test I find @Mikhail is right.
For C#, the default value(in local.settings.json or in application settings in portal) will be used if `connection` is ignored. But unfortunately there's no same settings for java.

You can add `@StorageAccount("YourStorageConnection")` below your `@FuncionName` as it's another valid way to choose. And value of `YourStorageConnection` in local.settings.json or in portal's application settings is up to you.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/master/azure-functions-maven-plugin#how-to), use `mvn azure-functions:add` to find four(Http/Blob/Queue/TimerTrigger) templates for java.